# top.frames wont work in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 html pages. main.html, page1.html and page2.html. I am displaying page1.html and page2.html in main.html using following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <frameset frameborder="1" rows="50%, *">
        <frame name="f1" src="Page1.html" />
        <frame name="f2" src="Page2.html"/>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

page1.html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
             .content {display:none;}
      </style>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="myjs.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
         <table id="resultDetails" border="1">
               <th>Result Details</th>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                  Click on me to see more details in other page
                  <div class="content">
                       <p> R1 data</p>
                  </div>
                  </td>

               </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And Page2.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
         <div id="myDiv">

         </div>

         <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="myjs.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript myjs.js

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
       var doc =window.top.frames['f2'].document;
       var divElmnt = $(doc.getElementById('myDiv'));

       $(divElmnt.html($(this).find('.content').html()));
    });
});
```

With this code, on clicking on table row, i am able to display the div "content" content in "mydiv" div of page2.

This works in IE and FF but wont work in Chrome. Error: doc is undefined.
What is the equivalent for window.top.frames['f2'] for chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with Chrome security flag for local files i.e., file:/// . After launching Chrome with "--allow-file-access-from-files" flag option, top.frames worked.

Also I found a useful document on Inter-Frame Communication with JavaScript [here](http://cross-browser.com/talk/inter-frame_comm.html).

Answer (score 0):

Give your FrameSet and your Frame an ID:

```
var $fs = $("#fs");
var f2 = $fs.find("#f2");
```

f2 is now a jQuery object.

Comment: I tried this but no success. `var $fs = $("#fs"); var doc = $fs.find("#f2"); var elmnt = doc.document;` Error: doc is undefined. Am I missing something here ?