# Unable to reload DIV using jquery Ajax in IE and Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

From my main page I open a fancybox on which I submit information via JQUERY AJAX request.

This submission should then populates DIV on the main page using the JQUERY .LOAD command.

Bizarrely I can only get this to work in Firefox.

I've like it to work for Chrome and IE too but cannot see a problem with my AJAX call.  Is anybody able to help?

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",  
          url: "../ajax/add-ingredient-to-recipe.php?"+dataString,  
          dataType: "html",
          data: dataString,  

          }).done(function (){

            top.frames.$.fancybox.close(true);
            top.frames.$('.calorie-table').load('./views/nutritional-data.tmp.php', function(){

                top.frames.$('.calorie-table').hide();
                top.frames.$('.calorie-table').fadeIn(800).css({backgroundColor: "#dddddd" });

            });
        });
```

Comment: Do you get any console errors in Chrome? See developers tab.

EDIT: hmm looks like top.frames is not working in Chrome. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762352/top-frames-wont-work-in-chrome

Comment: I suspect `top.frames` is what is causing your problem: http://cross-browser.com/talk/inter-frame_comm.html

Comment: I thought top.frames might be causing some issue, however, if I remove it fancybox won't even close.  I'll check out the link you provided Jeffrey

Comment: article read, tried using window.parent, parent.  and no luck

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out, hope it'll help anyone else having the same problem.

Am working on MAC so cannot test in IE but it works in Safari, Chrome, Firefox

I had to reload the div $('.calorie-table')  from the parent page and not from the AJAX request.

This was done in the script on the parent page that opened the fancybox, which now reads:

```
    $(".add-food-button").fancybox({
    width : 750,
    height : 430,
    fitToView : false,
    autoSize : false,
    transitionIn    :    'elastic',
    transitionOut    :    'elastic',
    type                : 'iframe',
    afterClose  : function() {
        $('.calorie-table').load('./views/nutritional-data.tmp.php');
        $('.calorie-table').hide();
        $('.calorie-table').fadeIn(800);
     }

    });
```

And my AJAX call now looks like this:

```
            $.ajax({
        type: "POST",  
          url: "../ajax/add-ingredient-to-recipe.php?"+dataString,  
          dataType: "html",
          data: dataString,  

          }).done(function (){

            window.top.$.fancybox.close(true);

        });
```